# Remove the action bar in the django template

Tags: django

How to remove the action bar from the top that contains the option Delete selected Users ?
remove the action bar completely and leave the space lank how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

found it

admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')

using this in the admin.py you can remove all the actions and the bar vanishes